# Nutch 1.11 on Cygwin

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, nutch

I am trying to run Nutch through Cygwin on a Windows 7 machine.

I cannot get past the injector phase when trying to crawl.

This is the error I am getting:

`2016-03-09 13:42:45,454 ERROR util.Shell - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path`

`java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.`

Later on it causes a NullPointerException:

2016-03-09 13:42:46,445 ERROR crawl.Injector - Injector: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1010)

Just after it gets past "Converting injected urls to crawl db entries."

Does anyone how to get past this error?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that  Nutch cannot read the input URL seed file (contains a list of URLs to be crawled). Please check the path to the file correct or not.

Hope this helps,

Le Quoc Do